# find all method not storing complete number in the list, when '+919888098880' is entered

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
#Find indian phone number in the text entered.

print('Enter text:')
para = input() #user's input
import re
phonenumreg = re.compile(r'[(\+91)|(0)]?[6-9]\d{9}')
no = phonenumreg.findall(para)
print(no) #print list
```

when I enter '`+917087708705`' and the list prints [`'+9170877087'`] but works fine for '`7087708705`' and '`07087708705`'

can someone explain me why?

Comment: is `7087708705` not a valid Indian phone number?

Comment: @Arne it is a valid number

Comment: @Arne but this number is without the country code

Answer (score 0):

You are using `[]` where you should use `(?:)`:

```
>>> r = re.compile(r'((?:\+91|0)?[6-9]\d{9})')
>>> r.findall('this in my list of numbers: 07087708715 and +917087708715')
['07087708715', '+917087708715']
```

Comment: As OP intends to use this with findall, you should use a non-capturing group instead of a capturing one.

Comment: then it will store the group separately in the list(which i don't want). I want the number to be stored on a single location so i can print them too.

Comment: Then make the group non-capturing (see updated answer).

Comment: @BartFriederichs thank you sir and can you explain why it wasn't working before.

Comment: @rahulverma because `[]` denotes a list of possibilities and inside that list, `()` don't seem to have much effect. So, on `+91..`, the first character `+` matches the list, the `9` matches the `[6-9]?` part, and then it looks for the next 9 digits: `170877087`.